# How to display 1 data if the same id and when clicked displays the same id in controller laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

How to display 1 data if the same id and when clicked displays the same id in controller laravel

how do you fix it?
[image]

> controller

```
public function daftar_paket(){
    if(!Session::get('login')){
        return redirect('/login')->with('alert','Kamu harus login dulu');
    }
    else{               
    $paket = DB::table('tbl_paket as a')
        ->select('*')
        ->join('tbl_profil_penyedia as b', 'a.id_profil_penyedia', '=', 'b.id_profil_penyedia')
        ->join('tbl_kategori_belanja as c', 'a.id_kategori_belanja', '=', 'c.id_kategori_belanja')
        ->join('tbl_kategori_produk as d', 'a.id_kategori_produk', '=', 'd.id_kategori_produk')
        ->join('tbl_pagu as e', 'a.id_pagu', '=', 'e.id_pagu')
        ->join('tbl_pembayaran as f', 'a.id_pembayaran', '=', 'f.id_pembayaran')
        ->get();
     $pesanan = DB::table('tbl_pesanan as a')
        ->select('*')
        ->join('tbl_bmn2 as b', 'a.kode_bmn', '=', 'b.kode_bmn')
        ->join('tbl_paket as c', 'a.id_paket', '=', 'c.id_paket')
        ->join('tbl_profil_penyedia as d', 'c.id_profil_penyedia', '=', 'd.id_profil_penyedia')
        ->join('tbl_kategori_produk as e', 'c.id_kategori_produk', '=', 'e.id_kategori_produk')
        ->get();
    return view('paket/home_daftar_paket',['paket' => $paket, 'pesanan' => $pesanan]);
    }
}
```

adding this can help?

> view

```
@foreach($pesanan as $p)


@php $status = $p->status_paket; @endphp

 @if ($status == 2)
 <table style="width:100%">
<tr>
    <td style="width: 15%;"><b>Nama Pesanan</b></td>
    <td style="width: 1%;">:</td>
    <td>{{$p->nama_pesanan }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 15%;"><b>Jenis Belanja</b></td>
    <td style="width: 1%;">:</td>
    <td>
            {{$p->nama_kategori_produk}}
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 15%;"><b>Kategori Belanja</b></td>
    <td style="width: 1%;">:</td>
    <td>{{$p->kode}} - {{$p->kategori_belanja}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 15%;"><b>Pagu</b></td>
    <td style="width: 1%;">:</td>
    <td>{{$p->kegiatan}}-{{$p->output}}-{{$p->sub_output}}-{{$p->komponen}}-{{$p->sub_komponen}}-{{$p->mak}} {{$p->uraian_mak}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 15%;"><b>Pembayaran</b></td>
    <td style="width: 1%;">:</td>
    <td>{{$p->jenis_pembayaran}}</td>
  </tr>
</table><br>
  <div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Pesanan')" >Pesanan</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Penawaran')" id="defaultOpen">Penawaran</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Negosiasi')">Negosiasi</button>
</div>
<div id="Pesanan" class="tabcontent">
    <div class="col-md-12">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">Kode BMN</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">Nama Barang</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 1px;">Kuantitas</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">Satuan Ukuran</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 25px;">Kode Unit</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="addRow" >
      <td class="col-xs-3" style="text-align: center;">{{$p->kode_bmn}}
      </td>

      <td class="col-xs-3" style="text-align: center;">{{$p->jenis_barang}}
      </td>
      <td class="col-xs-5" style="text-align: center;">{{$p->kuantitas}}
      </td>
      <td class="col-xs-5" style="text-align: center;">{{$p->satuan_ukuran}}
      </td>
      <td class="col-xs-5" style="text-align: center;">{{$p->kode_ruang}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

  <div class="col-md-1 pull-right"><br><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
</div>

</div>
<div id="Penawaran" class="tabcontent">
  <div class="col-md-12">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 20px;">Kode BMN</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 15px;">Nama Barang</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 5px;">Kuantitas</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 5px;">Satuan Ukuran</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 20px;">Kode Unit</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 5px;">Harga Satuan</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="addRow" >
      <td class="col-xs-3" style="text-align: center;">{{$p->kode_bmn}}
      </td>

      <td class="col-xs-3" style="text-align: center;">{{$p->jenis_barang}}
      </td>
      <td class="col-xs-5" style="text-align: center;">{{$p->kuantitas}}
      </td>
      <td class="col-xs-5" style="text-align: center;">{{$p->satuan_ukuran}}
      </td>
      <td class="col-xs-5" style="text-align: center;">{{$p->kode_ruang}}
      </td>
      <td class="col-xs-3">
        <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Enter title" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  <div class="col-md-1 pull-right"><br><br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="Negosiasi" class="tabcontent">
  <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="text-align: center; width: 1px;">No</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 20px;">Kode BMN</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 15px;">Nama Barang</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 5px;">Kuantitas</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 5px;">Satuan Ukuran</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 20px;">Kode Unit</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 5px;">Harga Satuan</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 10px;">Negosiasi</th>
      <th style="text-align: center; width: 5px;">Status Negosiasi</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>
  @php $no = 1; @endphp
  <tbody>
    <tr id="addRow" >
        <td>{{ $no++ }}</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">1010101008</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">meja</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">5</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">UNIT</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">10001</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">Rp50.000</td>
      <td class="col-xs-3">
        <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Enter title" />
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="" title="Sepakat"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up" style="color: green;"></i></a>
        &nbsp;
        <a href="" title="Tolak"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-down" style="color: red;"></i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="col-md-1 pull-right"><br><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
 @endif
```

[image]

How to?
How do you click on the 'submit bid' button to display the same ip list?
please help me

How to display 1 data if the same id and when clicked displays the same id in controller laravel

Comment: plz post your views code.

Comment: I think you can use `->groupBy('id_paket')`.

Comment: @Rob Where do I put it?

Comment: @TsaiKoga check

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused on your table structure but you could try using the [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-unique) method of collections. Give this a try:

```
// added ->unique()
return view('paket/home_daftar_paket',['paket' => $paket, 'pesanan' => $pesanan->unique('id_paket')]);
```

Comment: Can I call 1 foreign keys in 2 primary key?

Comment: you mean 2 entries having the same foreign key? isn't that what you have with your many-to-one relationship of tbl_pesanan to tbl_paket? I suggest you have a read on the recommended way to implement [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) in Laravel

Comment: How do you display the same foreign key id in the table? only the foreign key id is the same